# Display maven-excluded directories in STS package explorer?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite, m2e

I use  tags in my maven POM file to exclude a directory structure I do not want compiled:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/somedir/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However, I would like to have the directory displayed in the STS (3.9.2) Package Explorer. I've tried disabling all view filters, but the excluded directory doesn't display.  Is it possible to have maven-excluded directories displayed?

The project itself was created using "Import existing Maven project."

Comment: If they should not being compiled just remove them...

Comment: If that were the case, I wouldn't have posted.  The directory needs to stay due to refactoring issues.  Maven provides a way to exclude them from compilation.  My question isn't referring to that aspect. I understand if the community doesn't have the answer, but a non-answer really doesn't help.